# How are Google Plus emails interactive?

Tags: gmail, google-plus

I received a mail from Google+ saying that someone I knew recently joined Google+. The email had an interactive red-box which allowed me to add the user to my circles. As far as I am aware, emails do not include running JavaScript.

The original email:

[image: The original Email]

On hover:

[image: On hover]

Final result:

[image: Final result]

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a specific integration between Gmail and Google+. If you'll look at those messages in a regular email client, you won't see this interactivity. Only if you read them with Gmail web ui, Android or iOS Gmail clients.

As for specifics of how it's achieved, I imagine that is Google's 'secret sauce'. :)

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't it simple HTML and CSS? Or just a bit of JavaScript?

Comment: @terdon look at such message with any other email client, even those that support html/css/javascript and you won't see those interactions.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to reverse-engineer their "secret sauce" and run javascript inside Gmail?

Comment: @Capt.Nemo that's a really vague question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I was thinking from a security point of view, that whether someone else can use this to send me spam which (possibly) runs javascript. I'll try to look into it if I get some time.

Comment: If it was possible, don't you think 1) spammers would be abusing it already; 2) Google would block/secure that? :)

Comment: @Mxx 1) Perhaps they are and 2) Perhaps they try